# How to write a If then else constraint with continuous variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have a problem under investigation which requires if, elseif and else conditions to implement as a constraint in a mixed integer program. Any leads will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Let $x_t$, $y_t$ be continuous variables.

```py
if y[t] == 0:
   x[t] = 1 
elif y[t] == y[t-1]: 
   x[t] = x[t-1] * K #(constant) 
else: 
   y[t] = 1 - x[t]
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876411/how-to-write-a-if-then-else-constraint-with-continuous-variables

Comment: Are $x_t$ and $y_t$ nonnegative or free (unrestricted in sign)?

Comment: Thanks @prubin, appreciate your response on this modeling question. The values are non-negative and continuous for both variables. One quick catch is that the values of x[t] and y[t] lies between 0 and 1 - i.e.,  0 < x[t] < 1 and 0<y[t]<1. We can reduce the range of the bounds for x[t] as a <= x[t] <= b, for e.g.,  a =0.2 and b = 0.7. Let me know your inputs professor.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce three binary variables $z_{1t},z_{2t},z_{3t}$ corresponding
to the three conditions, along with the constraint $z_{1t}+z_{2t}+z_{3t}=1$
(exactly one condition must apply).

We want to enforce the following implications:

$$z_{1t}=1\implies\left(y_{t}=0\right)\wedge\left(x_{t}=1\right)
$$
$$z_{2t}=1\implies\left(y_{t}>0\right)\wedge\left(y_{t}=y_{t-1}\right)\wedge\left(x_{t}=Kx_{t-1}\right)
$$
$$z_{3t}=1\implies\left(y_{t}>0\right)\wedge\left(y_{t}\neq y_{t-1}\right)\wedge\left(y_{t}=1-x_{t}\right)
$$
Unfortunately, strict inequality ($>$) and "not equals" ($\neq$)
cannot be used in a mathematical program, so the best we can do is
an approximation using some small $\epsilon>0.$

In the following, $M_{1},\dots,M_{6}$ are sufficiently large positive
constants. The first implication can be expressed as follows.
$$y_{t}\le M_{1}\left(1-z_{1t}\right)
$$
$$x_{t}\le1+M_{2}\left(1-z_{1t}\right)
$$
$$x_{t}\ge z_{1t}
$$
The second implication is approximated as follows.
$$y_{t}\ge\epsilon z_{2t}
$$
$$y_{t}-y_{t-1}\le M_{3}\left(1-z_{2t}\right)
$$
$$y_{t-1}-y_{t}\le M_{3}\left(1-z_{2t}\right)
$$
$$x_{t}-Kx_{t-1}\le M_{4}\left(1-z_{2t}\right)
$$
$$Kx_{t-1}-x_{t}\le M_{4}\left(1-z_{2t}\right)
$$
To handle the $\neq$ element of the third implication, we need yet
another binary variable $w_{t}.$ The following approximates the third
implication.
$$y_{t}\ge\epsilon z_{3t}
$$
$$y_{t}-y_{t-1}\ge\epsilon z_{3t}-M_{5}w_{t}
$$
$$y_{t-1}-y_{t}\ge\epsilon z_{3t}-M_{5}\left(1-w_{t}\right)
$$
$$y_{t}-\left(1-x_{t}\right)\le M_{6}\left(1-z_{3t}\right)
$$
$$\left(1-x_{t}\right)-y_{t}\le M_{6}\left(1-z_{3t}\right)
$$
This necessarily eliminates some solutions that might
otherwise be feasible in the original model, such as $y_{t}=y_{t-1}$
and $x_{t}=Kx_{t-1}$ with $y_{t}\in\left(0,\epsilon\right)$.

**NOTE**: As pointed out by Rob Pratt in a comment, replacing $y_{t}\ge\epsilon z_{2t}$ and $y_{t}\ge\epsilon z_{3t}$ with $y_{t}\ge\epsilon (1 - z_{1t})$ is conceptually equivalent and yields a tighter relaxation.

Comment: I guess your second $y_t \ge \epsilon z_{2t}$ was intended to be $y_t \ge \epsilon z_{3t}$, but you can strengthen these two by instead imposing $y_t \ge \epsilon (z_{2t}+z_{3t})$, equivalently, $y_t \ge \epsilon (1-z_{1t})$.

Comment: @RobPratt: Yes, the last $z_{2t}$ was a copy-paste-forget-to-edit slip (fixed now). Thanks. I agree about the strengthening.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

$1-y_t-Mz_t \le x_t \le 1-y_t+Mz_t$

$ M(z_t-1) \le y_t - y_{t-1} \le M(1-z_t)$

$ L(1-z_t)+ y_{t-1}-Mz_t \le z_t +y_t \le y_{t-1} +M (1-z_t)+Lz_t $

$Kx_{t-1}+M(z_t-1) \le x_t \le Kx_{t-1} + M(1-z_t)$

With $z_t \in \{0,1 \}$, binary, $x_t,y_t = [L,M]$ and

Comment: Did you mean $z_t \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace?$

Comment: Your proposed formulation allows $y_t=0$ and $x_t=0$, which violates the first requirement that $y_t=0 \implies x_t=1$.